# Proving existence of Lebesgue-Null-Set when Fourier Coefficients zero

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be $2\pi$ periodical and integrable over $[0,2\pi]$, and the fourier coefficients $(c_{k})_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ , whereby $c_{k}=0$  $\forall k \in \mathbb Z$.

Show that a Lebesgue Null Set $\nu \subset \mathbb R$ exists, such that $f(x)=0$ $\forall x \in([0,2\pi]-\nu), $ in other words $\forall x \in \nu^{c}$.

I have a tough time with the existence of null set $\nu$, let alone the importance thereof. I mean if $c_{k}=0$ $\forall k \in \mathbb Z$, then 
$(Ff)(x):=\sum^{\infty}_{k=-\infty} c_{k}e^{ikx}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=-\infty} 0e^{ikx}=0$, so therefore $f(x)=0$ $\forall x\in \mathbb R$. What significance does the Null Set $\nu$ have?

Comment: How do you know that $(Ff)(x)=0$ for all $x$ implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x$?

Comment: Apologize if I'm making false statements here, just started with fourier series. But since isn't $(Ff)(x)$ (i.e. fourier series) an approximation of $f(x)$

Comment: It's certainly not true in general that $(Ff)(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$, if that's what you mean.

Comment: So the $x \in \nu$ are the points at which $(Ff)(x) \neq f(x)$?

Comment: You are simply trying to show that if all Fourier coefficients of $f$ are $0,$ then $f=0$ a.e.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $\hat f(k)=0$ for all $k,$ then

$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)p(t)\,dt=0$$

for all trigonometric polynomials $p.$ Because trigonometric polynomials are dense in the continuous $2\pi$-periodic functions (with respect to the sup-norm on $[0,2\pi]),$ we have

$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)g(t)\,dt=0$$

for every continuous $2\pi$-periodic function $g.$ This will lead to

$$\int_0^{2\pi} |f(t)|\,dt=0$$

if you invoke some well known theorems in measure theory.

Comment: The first part "trigonometric polynomials are dense in the continuous 2π-periodic functions (with respect to the sup-norm on [0,2π])" needs a proof and is not easy. If I remember correctly, it is due to Weierstrass. The proof requires considering the Fourier expansion of the continuous function and then considering the Casero summation...

Comment: The second part, C([a,b]) is L^1-dense in L^1([a,b]) ultimately boils down to the regularity of Lebesgue measure. Or in Royden's terminology: Littlewood's first principle.

Comment: This question can be generalized very far: Let $G$ be a locally compact Abelian group. Then the Fourier-Stieltjes transform $M(G)\rightarrow B(\hat{G})$, $\mu\mapsto \hat{\mu}$ is injective. For this question, $G$ is just the normalized circle group $\mathbb{T}$.

Comment: Two more remarks:

1. For the proof of the theorem, one may consult the textbook "A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis, 2nd Edition" written by Gerald B. Folland, Corollary 4.34 (Of course, it is not a one-line proof.)

2. The injectivity of Fourier transform was first studied by Cantor. When Cantor attacked this problem, he considered certain kind of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (which becomes point set topology on $\mathbb{R}$). As a by-product, this started two important fields in mathematics: Set Theory and Point Set Topology.